# laravel 5.3 authentication using laravel-passport?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I have installed package in Passport Oauth for authentication. I need to check the authentication using laravel-passport to my custom tables with my fields not the USER table email and password.

How to authenticate using Passport Oauth for my table other than Users table.?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create new User model(which linked to your's table) and link it with path: providers.users.model in **config/auth.php** file?

Comment: Yes.But I don't need to login process, I need to just authenticate the key using laravel-passport oauth method in the custom table.